# better implementation of command line randomization with Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

`enter code here`This is a one liner to randomize STDIN, the aim is to feed a list of files and tail -N gives you N random out of a huge list (bigger than N anyway):

```
 ruby -e 'arr=[]; ARGF.each {|line| arr << line}; puts arr.sort_by {rand}'
```

I am wondering if there is a shorter version.

The winner is:

```
find . -type f | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.sort_by {rand}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
ruby -e 'puts ARGF.sort_by{rand}'
```

Comment: It does not seem to work... "e:1:in `each_line': private method `rand' called for "./""

Comment: you mean: ruby -e 'puts ARGF.sort_by {rand}' and yes! :)

Comment: Sounds like a Ruby version conflict, the `&:rand` syntax works for me but your `{rand}` version is the same thing and even uses 2 fewer characters (if you get rid of that space :).

Answer (score 1):

This what you're looking for?

```
ruby -e 'p ARGF.to_a.sample'
```

Comment: I need to randomize a list what I get on STDIN, see example above

Answer (score 0):

Who needs stdin?

```
Dir["*"].select {|v| v if File.file?(v)}.sort_by {rand}
```